# Выбор значения по умолчанию для дочерних классов

Tags: php, ооп, наследование

Доброй ночи. Имеется структура классов, которая представлена ниже. То есть, родительный класс, и множество дочерних (`People` как пример). В родительском классе имеются константы, скажем это виды языков. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы человек, перед использованием скажем, класса, `People`, прописал язык какую-нибудь настройку (по умолчанию), чтобы язык, скажем был `EN`. И во всех дочерних классах использовалось -`EN`.

```
abstract class Guide
{
    const RU = 1;
    const EN = 2;

    public abstract function members(): array;
}

class People extends Guide
{
    public function members(): ?array
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Такое вообще возможно, или я иду не в том направлении? Может есть какие-нибудь другие варианты для реализации всего этого дела? Буду рад за любую помощь. Спасибо :)

Comment: Честно ко мне пришла в голову безумно дурная идея использовать в каждом дочернем класс трейт.. Но это дико и неправильно.

Comment: статичное свойство класса вам в помощь

Comment: @teran, спасибо, попробуем)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В абстрактном классе делается абстрактный метод `getLang` который должен возвращать язык.

В потомке `People` перекрывается этот метод - возвращает, например, `EN`

Все потомки `People` будут возвращать при обращении к этому методу тоже `EN`, но, если понадобится, могут и перекрыть этот метод и возвращать `RU`